# How to do multiple selectors in YUI

Tags: javascript, yui, yui2

How can i do multiples selectors in yui (yui 2) like in jquery :

```
$('h1, h2, el1, el2, .content, .title').css('color', 'red');
```

How can this one be written in yui (without doing YAHOO.util.Dom.addClass on each element seperately)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some of the DOM methods of YUI accept an array of elements to act on, and the addStlye() method is one of them, so you should be able to do:

```
YAHOO.util.Dom.setStyle(['el1', 'el2'], 'color', 'red');
```

Think it only works with ids though, so the first element should have an id of el1, etc...

EDIT:

You can also use the `YAHOO.util.Selector` module to query the DOM and return the array of elements to pass to `setStyle()`, e.g:

```
var els = YAHOO.util.Selector.query('h1, h2, h3, .some-element');

YAHOO.util.Dom.setStyle(els, 'color', 'red');
```

Comment: Sounds like the OP is looking for the selector bit though…

Comment: thanks a lot specialy for YAHOO.util.Selector , didnt know of it before

Answer (score 3):

Or in YUI 3:

```
Y.all('h1, h2, h3, .content, .title').setStyle('color', 'red');
```

Comment: I am loving what I have seen so far of YUI3, some great stuff there :)

Comment: How would I do something similar for the Y.Anim class? Setting the node config to a string like you suggest above doesn't seem to work.